# Add output to Azure Devops pipeline Job Summary Screen

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a simple build and release pipeline in Azure Devops. I notice that when it finishes, it shows a summary screen and selects the *job* not the final *task*. A simple example is:

```
Agent: Hosted Agent
Started: Just now
Duration: 4s

Job live console data:
Starting: Job Deploy Development
Finishing: Job Deploy Development
```

Is there any way to add to this output stream (such as echo "##vso[job.xxx ...")? I checked the pipeline logging options and only see ways to interact with an individual task screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, this is not available.

The [Logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell) are for tasks and scripts communicate with the agent, not the entire job scope.